# Extracting, getting jp(e)g or png file format out of mp4 on Linux

Tags: image, video

How do we get jp(e)g or png file format out of mp4 one using some Linux CLI tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffmpeg.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy album-art.jpg
```